# I've got a '-15' in achievements drop-down but can't see why in thread

Tags: support, down-votes

I answered [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215738/why-do-we-need-to-find-the-current/215781#215781) and it's showing up with a -15 in the achievements drop down. When I look at the question I've got one up-vote and no down-votes.

Anyone know what that signifies?

Comment: The accepted answer was probably changed.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silent rep changes. Some events, when done quickly enough after the initial event, will just be silently adjusted, removing both events. If enough time passes (I think 1 UTC day), it will no longer silently change.

Accepts and Unaccepts. Down vote and Up vote. Bounty. User removal.

If enough time has passed, you'll notice a new event line on your reputation in your profile, and it will say Unaccept.

As @Matt has pointed out, -15 would indicate a removal of the 15 rep accept bonus.